# Swing Draw 1px border lines between components in a GridBagLayout component

Tags: java, swing, layout, border

I have components laid out in a GridBagLayout. I want a 1px black line between all the components, as well as around the JPanel itself.

Currently, I am using a MatteBorder to do this. The parent component has a 1px MatteBorder on the top and left edges. Each child component has a 1px MatteBorder on the right and bottom edges. The horizontal and vertical gaps are zero on the GridBagLayout.

This mostly works, except I'm getting occasional gaps where the child borders meet the parent border. 
[image: Gaps in borders]

I suspect this is due to a rounding/floating point inaccuracy in the distribution of extra space to the child components.

Is there a better way to achieve this look?

Attached is a simpler example:

```
public class SSBGuiTest extends JDialog {
    public SSBGuiTest(Frame owner) {
        super(owner);
        initComponents();
    }

    public SSBGuiTest(Dialog owner) {
        super(owner);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        wrapperPanel = new JPanel();
        panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder = new JPanel();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel();
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        label2 = new JLabel();
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        label3 = new JLabel();

        //======== this ========
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //======== wrapperPanel ========
        {
            wrapperPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));
            wrapperPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            //======== panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder ========
            {
                panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 0, Color.black));
                panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                ((GridBagLayout)panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder.getLayout()).columnWidths = new int[] {0, 0};
                ((GridBagLayout)panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder.getLayout()).rowHeights = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0};
                ((GridBagLayout)panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder.getLayout()).columnWeights = new double[] {1.0, 1.0E-4};
                ((GridBagLayout)panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder.getLayout()).rowWeights = new double[] {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0E-4};

                //======== panel1 ========
                {
                    panel1.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 1, Color.black));
                    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                    //---- label1 ----
                    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    label1.setText("label1");
                    panel1.add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder.add(panel1, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                    new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

                //======== panel2 ========
                {
                    panel2.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 1, Color.black));
                    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                    //---- label2 ----
                    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    label2.setText("label2");
                    panel2.add(label2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder.add(panel2, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                    new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

                //======== panel3 ========
                {
                    panel3.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 1, Color.black));
                    panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                    //---- label3 ----
                    label3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    label3.setText("label3");
                    panel3.add(label3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder.add(panel3, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                    new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            }
            wrapperPanel.add(panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
        contentPane.add(wrapperPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private JPanel wrapperPanel;
    private JPanel panelWithTopLeftMatteBorder;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JPanel panel3;
    private JLabel label3;
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd use `BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color, thickness)` rather than ...`matteBorder`, since `LineBorder` seems to be a bit closer to what you're looking to do. As a convenience, you could also use `LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder()`.

If the outsides of some components aren't quite hitting the insides of their containers, check that the containers (i.e. outer components) don't have non-zero insets set!

---

An alternate solution might be to let your background container have a black background and 1 pixel insets, and place non-bordered components on it with 1 pixel gaps between them. That should result in very precise black lines everywhere you don't have a component on top, and also eliminates the problem of multiple borders meeting up and resulting in a double-width border.

---

Finally, it looks to me like you're using components to draw tables. Do you need these components to have behavior of some sort, or would it be fine to really just put tables on your components? You could do this pretty conveniently using e.g. `JLabel`s `JTextPanel`s and setting their `text` properties to HTML for whatever you'd like to display. Java incorporates a fairly sophisticated HTML layout engine which even handles a goodly subset of CSS, either inline or even from a `href`'d file.

Comment: Carl, I'm trying to get precise borders. If two components with line border butt up against each other, there will be a 2px border there instead of 1px.

Comment: I did try the black background, with 1px padding, and white components overlaid, but the top and bottom child components had thicker borders at the top and bottom for some reason. Plus, I'm generating a PDF from this component, and am concerned that the black background might be less optimal PDF instructions than actual line coordinates.

Comment: @Sam Barnum: Thanks for the clarifications! I haven't fully solved your problem but I've been able to reproduce it. By setting different background colors on the various panels, I was able to show that your inner components do not fully fill the outer panel: There are 2px gaps on the top, right and bottom. Maybe there are insets you're not aware of or haven't looked at?

Comment: @Sam Barnum: Your solution *almost* works, so I'm hesitant to question it, but why the roundabout way to generate your PDF? You could generate that kind of picture pretty easily using XML tools and Xalan-FO or such... is there a real requirement to have this stuff on a screen as actual components?

Comment: @Carl, the PDF generation is secondary, most of this is for a complex swing application. One feature of the app is to generate a PDF representation of what's on screen. I don't think there are any hidden insets, it's all in the code in the sample. I think GridBagLayout might just not be all that accurate if components are set to grow.

Comment: @Sam Barnum: Thanks for some more clarification. Here are two more suggestions: (1) If it's not necessary for fields of the table to be actual components (responding to clicks and so on) then you have the option of either painting your tables using the methods in `Graphics`, or you could use HTML to make that process even simpler. (2) Interfaces `LayoutManager` and `LayoutManager2` offer a number of alternatives. While I enjoy the intellectual challenge of `GridBagLayout`, depending on the application others, such as `BoxLayout`, `SpringLayout` and `GroupLayout` are simpler and more tractable.